# How do I Disable Google Drive Revision Pruning?

Tags: version-control, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

Each time a file is edited (Pdf, Google doc, ect.) there is a new revision. By default, Google drive deletes file revisions older than 30 days or 100 versions... How can I switch this off?

My end goal is keep all revisions of all files stored in Google drive.

I found this resource, but I don't know how to implement it yet. Would you please walk me through?

[How to use the "KeepRevisionForever" property to keep all file versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50930965/how-to-use-the-keeprevisionforever-property-to-keep-all-file-versions)

Thank you so much!

Comment: You want to set `keepRevisionForever` to `true` for the existing file. For this, you can achieve this using the method of "Files: update" in Drive API. Also, you can test the method at ["Try this API"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update). Access to "Try this API" and set `keepRevisionForever` to `true`, then, when you set the file ID and click "EXECUTE" button, `keepRevisionForever` of file is set to `true`. But in the current stage, unfortunately, it seems that there are no methods for checking whether `keepRevisionForever` of the file has already been `true`.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your swift response! I clicked on the link you posted, which opened the "Try this API" popup window. From there, I set "keepRevisionForever" to "true". What do I set the "fileId" as? It won't let me click "EXECUTE" because "fileId is required."

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. `fileId` is `The ID of the file.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

Answer (score 1):

You want to set `keepRevisionForever` to `true` for the existing file.

For this, you can achieve this using the method of "Files: update" in Drive API.

Also, you can test the method at "[Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)".

Access to "Try this API" and set `keepRevisionForever` to `true`, then, when you set the file ID and click "EXECUTE" button, `keepRevisionForever` of file is set to `true`.

But in the current stage, unfortunately, it seems that there are no methods for checking whether `keepRevisionForever` of the file has already been `true`.

Comment: @Tanaike post it as an answer and I will delete this one.

Comment: Thank you for your support. In this case, I would like to respect your support. Thank you, too. So I would like to upvote it.